# HTML <html> size - computed size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am confused by the size of the `<html>` reported by Chrome browser.
I am working in full-screen with screen resolution `1360x768`. I use this css to put the full screen image on the background:

```
bg-img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:1360px; height:768px; }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't show up the image on full screen, and is smaller. I go for the inspect element on `<html>` markup and see size like 1790 x 768. Computed size reported by Chrome:

```
display: block;
height: 768px;
width: 1790.6666259765625px;
```

What I found this works OK in `--chrome-frame` mode (width: 1360px, but have another problem with extensions so cant use that)

What is going on?

---

The solution with `%` even if works OK for background image, doesn't solve my problem because I have other `absolute` elements on this background and I can't position them with `%`, because it is not enough precise.

---

I though that maybe reported 1790.6666259765625px is caused by my extended desktop and 2'nd monitor, but after disabling the same problem.

Comment: You have to set the `body` tag to a fixed height from what I remember. Try with `body { min-height: 768px; }`. Background image doesn't enlarge the document itself, it's always 'cut' by the actual 'data' height.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work : body { min-width:1360px; min-height:768px; width:1360px; height:768px; margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; } would be better if I could force <html> to size.

Comment: Is it possible that I don't have other choice than '100%'?

Comment: What about setting a block element like a `div` for displaying data and set the min-height to it?

Comment: Even If I have only <div style="min-height:792px; border: solid;"> I see white space below.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead**

```
bg-img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:1360px; height:768px; }
```

**Try to do this:**

```
bg-img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

It always works to me and will work in different monitors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This solution even if works OK for image, doesn't solve my problem because I have other `absolute` elements on this background and i can't position them with `%`, because it is not enough precise.

Answer (score 1):

You want CSS3 `background-size` which allows you to adapt the image ratio regardless of the screen resolution. Make sure you match the CSS selector and adjust the URL to the image you are using...

```
.bg-img
{
 background-image: url(wallpaper.jpg);
 background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

For a live demonstration first pick a wallpaper at my site...

http://www.jabcreations.com/forums/?prompt=themes-wallpaper

...and then change the "wallpaper Effect" here...

http://www.jabcreations.com/forums/?prompt=options-basic

You'll find the relevant CSS code at `themes/style_user.css` once it's applied.

Comment: Thanks. This solution even if works OK for image, doesn't solve my problem because I have other `absolute` elements on this background and i can't position them with %, because it is not enough precise. All elements relay on size of HTML and are defined in `px`.